# save global variables in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables

I have a module with a load of global variables.
I would like the name of the global variables in this module to be saved in the first column, and the global variable value to be saved in the second column

i.e

```
public variable1 as string
public variable2 as string
public variable3 as string

variable1 = David
variable2 = Chicken
Variable3 = Apple
```

column a: variable1, variable2, variable3
column b: david,chicken,apple

Comment: Are these global variables that change, and you want to take a snapshot? Are these global constants that you just want to copy into a spreadsheet once? Are you looking to view and update these global variables from a spreadsheet? You're not very clear on what you are trying to do and why, without those details it's difficult to give you a good answer.

Comment: these are a snapshop. basically whenever I debug my project, the global variables get reset. so I cant run code after the debug becuase the global variables have been reset. So i wanted to save a snap shop of these variables so that i can then reload them with an alternative code?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three ways you could go about this.

You could set up your global variables as properties and have thier values stored in cells on your worksheet. Execution of your code will be slower, but the values will persist and be viewable/editable on the spreadsheet.

For example, to define a string property 'Foo' that acts like a global variable put this in your global module:

```
Public Property Get Foo() As String
  Foo = DebugSheet.[B2]
End Property

Public Property Let Foo(value As String)
  DebugSheet.[B2] = value
End Property
```

You could also use named ranges for globals, eg DebugSheet.[Foo]

A third way would be to have hardcoded save and load routines that explicitly save each global to a specific cell in your spreadsheet. This only works if the save routine has run since you last changed a global variable.

#### Edit

As a side note I'd recommend the properties. It takes more to write it, but later on if you want to switch back to VBA variables (for speed) it requires fewer code changes than using named ranges.

#### Edit 2

If you want to be crazy and create self modifying code you would get the workbooks VBProject, get the component for the module that contains your globals, then get the lines from its CodeModule.

```
set module = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("GlobalsModule").CodeModule
code = module.Lines(1, module.CountOfLines)
```

You'd then have your module code in the string variable `code`, you'd parse that then write your results back. Not easy or recommended.

Comment: The Property is good @AndASM and you could also combine it with the Formulas tab, Create From Selection, so that the reference to the specific worksheet and cell(s) is unnecessary.

Comment: I was wondering whether there was something more automated that could be done? i.e everytime I add a new global variable it automatically takes it and exports its name to a spreadsheet.?

Comment: The automatic ways of adding new global variables are messy. They involve using the VBE library to dynamically read or modify your VBA code. This will likely result in your workbook being detected as a virus and blocked from email. As well as making the code much more complicated.

Comment: Thanks My boss wanted the more automated one, the method I wrote was: Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Variable1", Range("b2").value = variable1     my manager liked it but wanted the automatic version. I looked at vbe library from cpearson.com.but couldnt find the code that corresponds to sourcing existing global variables. do u have any idea of how to do that, then ill try and work it out from there

Comment: Obviously I'm not going to write the code for you, especially not the code I recommend you avoid. You'd use VBE to read the code module, add the variable name to your target sheet, then create the new properties and comment out the existing variable line. Self modifying code.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using public variables why not just put the values in the sheet with a description in the first column and the value in the second.

```
Column A       Column B
Variable1      David
Variable2      Chicken
Variable3      Apple
```

It might slow down your code a bit, but might be easier you wouldn't have to update the variable in 2 places.

You would probably to write some functions, one to set the value and one to get the value. These functions would loop through column A until the description is found and then either set the value in column B or retreive it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to loop, they could be set as Defined Names. Highlight the 6 cells and choose the Formulas tab, Create From Selection. In code these values can be referenced as `Range("Variable1")` or even `[Variable1]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Use VBA.Collection or Scripting.Dictionary to hold the values.
Then you can iterate through the items at any time and input/output them.
This might be the best and fastest solution.

### Option 2

[Programm the VBA Editor](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx).

- Parse the target CodeModule containing the variables
- Extract all global variable definitions
- From these definitions, create dynamically a new CodeModule
- In this dynamic CodeModule, create a procedure which outputs the values of the variables
- Call this procedure (this could be the hard part)

Hint: Do not go for this option.

Comment: I don't see how using a Collection or Dictionary gets around the issue of the variables being reset?

Comment: In option 1, the collection must by saved to sheet or file before a reset, indeed.